# set ImageView' height accordingly to its set width and aspect ratio, in a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have below a `ScrollView` so that the user would be able to scroll the question container(`ImageView` + `TextView`), if the questions text is very enormous. The problem is that I want the `ImageView` to take the height based on its aspect ratio and width set with the help of `layout_width` set to `match_parent` attribute.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/set_1_question_2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="@string/app_set_1_question_2_text" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

As in the *Image* below, by hovering the **`LinearLayout`** of **`ScrollView`** parent, it's showing that it's height is equal with image original height ~ 1100px + the height of **`TextView`**.

[image]

Wherever I put the `layout_height` set to `wrap_content` or 0dp with weight set 1, it seems that it doesn't work either.

Any appropriate solution would be very helpful, because I am just starting off with `Android` developing and I am stuck with this problem.

**EDIT:**

After searching through all methods for ImageView on https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html, I found this method:

```
android:adjustViewBounds    Set this to true if you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.
```

Which works perfectly for my case, thanks for everyone that tried to solve my problem. :)